# Router outlet without tag?

Tags: angular, router

If I use a router-outlet or any other selector for any component like  I end up with the HTML code of the component inside the tag like this:

```
<component>
  <!-- component html here -->
</component>
```

What I need this the component html only replacing the

```
<component></component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>`
HTML code of the component inside the tag like this.